# Add textblock to ellipse in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, textblock, ellipse

How to add a TextBlock to an Ellipse in WPF/Silverlight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `Grid`, place the `Ellipse` followed by the `TextBlock` in the `Grid`.

```
<Grid>
   <Ellipse ...  />
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```